# Visual Studio 2013 - the system cannot find reference specified

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I googled and checked existing post here but didn't find any relevant post so here is my question.

I am using VS2013 Primium edition. I have few class library projects(all using framework 4.0). When these class libraries become part of Web Solution, reference paths in the class library are shown and project compiles fine as shown below. 
[image: When class library is part of Web Solution]

However, same class library project doesn't load reference paths when it becomes part of Windows Service Solution.

[image: When project is loaded in windows service]

I doubled checked all my projects are using same framework version. Any idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

finally I am able to resolve it.

After recreated my library project inside my Windows Service Solution as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468422/visual-studio-wont-find-references).

I opened same library project in my web solution. Somehow, my web solution adds nuGet restore tags in my library project file.

```
<RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>  
<Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />  
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">  
<PropertyGroup>
  <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
</PropertyGroup>
<Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
```

These tags were causing trouble. Once I removed those tags as described [here](https://cmatskas.com/disabling-nuget-package-restore/). it fixed my issue.